# How to subset the rows of dataset from the values of another vector in R

Tags: r, database, subset

I have a data frame like this

```
n <- c("abc;xml", "abc;derm;sip", "xol;exp", "ban;lopic", "LPLL2", "LPLL")
fac <- sample(n, 6, replace = F)
d <- data.frame(x = 1:6, fac = fac)
d

  x          fac
1 1      abc;xml
2 2    ban;lopic
3 3      xol;exp
4 4 abc;derm;sip
5 5         LPLL
6 6        LPLL2
```

and a vector like this:

```
vec=c("abc", "xml","sip", "exp", "lopic", "LPLL")
```

I would like to subset the rows which have similar match with values in the vectors.

I tried this code:

```
nam="abc|xml|sip|exp|lopic|LPLL"
subset(d, regexpr(nam, d$fac) > 0)
```

But it doesn't work correctly, because include and LPLL2!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your regex will find any match, even if it is not exact. This will work:

```
index <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(d$fac), split = ";"), function(x) any(x%in% vec))
d[index, ]
  x          fac
1 1      xol;exp
2 2      abc;xml
3 3    ban;lopic
5 5         LPLL
6 6 abc;derm;sip
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
ind<-lapply(lapply(strsplit(as.character(d$fac),';'),function(x)x %in% vec),any)
d[unlist(ind),]
```